# WebEx's Personal Room on Linux/Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, conferencing

How do I access WebEx's "Personal Room" on my Ubuntu 14.04 operating system?  Currently, when I attempt to access WebEx's "Personal Room", WebEx responds with an error message stating that my browser is not supported.  My browser is FireFox, but the same error message is displayed with any browser I use (Chromium, Epiphany).

**What I've already done:**
Originally, before WebEx's "Personal Room" was made known/available to me, I was attempting to access WebEx's "Meetings".  After reading several threads on "how to use WebEx on Linux", I installed some libraries (I don't remember which ones, but they were somewhat related to Java), and I now have limited access to WebEx's "Meetings".  Specifically, I can share my desktop, view a shared desktop, and record the meeting.  However, I cannot share a file and I cannot view a shared file.

These two features of WebEx, "Meetings" & "Personal Room", seem to be closely related.  I've partially solved my challenge with "Meetings", but I have not made any progress accessing "Personal Room".

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest (Dec 2015) documentation for Webex [Operating System and Browser Support](https://help.webex.com/docs/DOC-2222), in footnote 2 they say:

> Linux is not supported for Personal Rooms.

You may not give up all hope, as footnote 3 says Firefox 64-bit is not supported, which is not accurate as I use 64-bit Firefox with 64-bit Java 7.x (Oracle JDK) by manually symlinking `libnpjp2.so` to `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/`.

But now with MacOS not using Java and using a plugin instead (footnote 1), it seems unlikely to use Webex Personal Rooms on Linux, unless they release a plugin for us.